# PostgreSQL bytea network traffic double expected value

Tags: postgresql

I'm investigating a bandwidth problem and stumbled on an issue with retrieving a bytea value. I tested this with PostgreSQL 10 and 14, the respective psql clients and the psycopg2 client library.

The issue is that if the size of a bytea value is eg. 10 MB (I can confirm by doing `select length(value) from table where id=1`), and I do `select value from table where id=1`, then the amount of data transferred over the socket is about 20MB. Note that the value in the database is pre-compressed (so high entropy), and the table is set to not compress the bytea value to avoid double work.

I can't find any obvious encoding issue since it's all just bytes. I can understand that the psql CLI command may negotiate some encoding so it can print the result, but psycopg2 definitely doesn't do that, and I experience the same behaviour.

I tested the same scenario with a text field, and that nearly worked as expected. I started with copy paste of lorem ipsum and it transferred the correct amount of data, but when I changed the text to be random extended ASCII values (higher entropy again), it transferred more data than it should have. I have compression disabled for all my columns so I don't understand why that would happen.

Any ideas as to why this would happen?

Comment: "*it's all just bytes*" - is it? Did you read the socket protocol specification to back up that assumption?

Comment: What version of `psycopg`? I suspect you may see a difference between `psycopg2` and `psycopg`(3). For more information see  [Binary psycopg2](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#adapt-binary) vs [Binary types(3)](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/params.html#binary-data).  In other words the `text` vs `binary` modes Laurenz Albe talks about in his answer.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver psycopg2-binary-2.9.3. I will test psycopg (3). Is think you're correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is normal. By default, values are transferred as strings, so a `bytea` would be rendered in hexadecimal numbers, which doubles its size.

As a workaround, you could transfer such data in binary mode. The frontend-backend protocol and the C library offer support for that, but it will depend on your client API whether you can make use of that or not.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz. I didn't pick up that the data is actually encoded as hex strings. I read the docs and thought nibbles are translated into hex, and it's just a different base for the same data. The encoding explains the size. I will try psycopg 3.x and see if that works.

Comment: I can confirm that psycopg 3 using the instructions at https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/params.html#binary-data works correctly.

Comment: Both `psycopg2` and `psycopg3` work correctly they just use different modes to transmit the data.